# How to lag dichotomous and continuous variables with R?

Tags: r

I am using Cox regression model with time-varying covariates. I need to lag all my covariates with one period (years) in order to avoid the problem of simultaneity of cause and effect. So I wonder how I can do it in R? I have both dichotomous and continuous time-varying covariates.

Sample of my data:

```
country  year            X  X1
      A  1990  380,4009552   0
      A  1991  384,1316813   0
      B  1990  569,9407288   1
      B  1991  622,3796544   1
      C  1990   690,842629   1
```

Comment: Your decimal separator is `,`, right?

Comment: @Pascal That's right. Taken from my .csv Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for lagging that I admittedly copied from someone else on here. This particular setup is written for data.tables, but you can rewrite for a data.frame simply enough.

```
lagging<-function (data, var, time) 
{
    return(c(rep(NA, time), head(data[, eval(as.name(var))], 
        (length(data[, eval(as.name(var))]) - time))))
}

#how to use:
df[,lagX:=lagging(df,'X',1)]

#also, if you want to run one ahead--

forwarding<-function (data, var, time) 
{
    return(c(tail(data[, eval(as.name(var))], (length(data[, 
        eval(as.name(var))]) - time)), rep(NA, time)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason. I try to make it work for my data, but I get error message. Here is what I did: mydata[,lagGDP=lagging(mediate,'GDP',1)]. Here is the Error: **Error in `[.data.frame`(mediate, , lagGDP:= lagging(mydata "GDP", 1)) : 
  unused argument (lagGDP := lagging(mydata, "GDP", 1))**

Comment: `mydata[,lagDP:=lagging(mediate,'GDP',1)]`

In data table you assign with `:=`